# Different users using the same dashboard url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have  user model with three roles, admin,buyer,seller.
I also have a dashboard controller, currently on login each user is directed to a different dashboard action...

application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource.role
      when "buyer"
      buyer_dash_path
      when "seller"
      seller_dash_path
      when "admin"
      admin_dash_path
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 get 'dashboard/admin' => 'dashboard#admin', as: 'admin_dash'
 get 'dashboard/seller' => 'dashboard#seller', as: 'seller_dash'
 get 'dashboard/buyer' => 'dashboard#buyer', as: 'buyer_dash'
```

so when a buyer logs in they are redirected to '/dashboard/buyer', an admin is redirected to '/dashboard/admin' etc..
How do I remove the action name so all users are redirected to '/dashboard' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better using the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :dashboard, only: [:index] #-> url.com/dashboard

#app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
   def index
      case current_user.role
        when "admin"
          #do something
          render "dashboard/admin"
        when "seller"
          #do something
          render "dashnoard/seller"
        else
          #do something
      end
   end
end

#app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb
<!-- do stuff in here -->
```

Comment: I'd rather not have a ton of if statements hiding or displaying content depending on which was the current role, it's why I want them in separate views

Comment: You can have separate views with this code. Just do `render "dashboard/admin" ` etc

Comment: perfect, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Thanks man, give my regards to Donatello and Michelangelo please!

Answer (score 0):

You could leave only one route:

```
get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'
```

And introduce new action in controller:

```
def index
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user
  send(current_user.role)
  render current_user.role
end
```

If current user is for example `seller` then `index` action will execute following:

```
seller()
render 'seller'
```

With these changes you don't need to change anything else in your app.

Comment: And with this approach it would be better to make `admin`/`seller`/`buyer` methods private